# why does my PyCharm shell behaving weird?

Tags: function, class, pycharm

When i execute my bi() function to transform decimal to binary, after implement a stacking class (just for my studies), PyCharm behaves this way:

```
>>> bi(13)
1 1 0 1 >>> bi(14)
1 1 1 0 >>> bi(134)
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
>>>
```

So, when i write my function again in the last line and press enter, for example **>>>bi(12)**, it goes after the last result, in this case would be **1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 >>>bi(12)**

my code:

```
class Pilha():
    def __init__(self):
        'inicializar uma lista para armazenar os elementos da pilha'
        self.data = []

    def push(self, x):
        'insere um elemento ao final da pilha'
        self.data.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        'remove o último elemento da pilha'
        if len(self.data) > 0:
            return self.data.pop(-1)

    def top(self):
        'retorna o último elemento da pilha'
        if len(self.data) > 0:
            return self.data[-1]

    def empty(self):
        'consulta se a pilha está vazia'
        return not len(self.data) > 0


def bi(x):
    p = Pilha()
    while x > 0:
        resto = x % 2
        p.push(resto)
        x = x // 2

    while not p.empty():
        print(p.pop(), end=" ")
```

I tried rerunning the shell and restarting PyCharm.
Also tried on IDLE the same code and everything seems ok

Comment: You use `print(p.pop(), end=" ")`, so you are not writing an end of line after your program exit.  Just put a `print()` at very top of your program.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi i used `end=" "` so the binary output wouldn't be with 0's or 1's printed on separated lines. Where exactly do you mean putting `print()` at very top of my program?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi oh i see! idk if this is what you mean, but i just put another `print()` just below everything, inside the `def bi(x)` in the same identation line of the other two `while` and it kind worked, i have a clean output now

Comment: Sorry. I was meaning "at very bottom". (so just to print the end of line character before yhe program end)